# Not able to fire javascript Alert message in asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, message, alert

I am using toolscriptmanager in my application. I used javascript alert messages as follows :

1. `StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
           s.Append("<script language='javascript'>");
           s.Append("alert('You Are Not Authorized To View This Page')");
           s.Append("</script>");
           RegisterStartupScript("You Are Not Authorized To View This Page", s.ToString());`
2. `ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Success", "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Your are not authorized to view this page!');`
3. `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Please enter a valid Order ID')");`
4. `Console.Write("<script>alert('Invalid USer')</script>");`

Also used scriptmanager.registerclientscript but nothing is working. I am not using update panel, using toolscriptmanager.

Where is the mistake ?

Answer (score 0):

this.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "startUpScriptBlock", "alert('TESZT')", true);

Comment: What do you want to achieve with the JS?
The code above is tested. It's simple in the Page_Load method. The "tricky" part is the last argument, which tell the script manager to put the string between script tags automatically.
What version of asp do you use and what the browser you tested in?